# Content assist not working for joinfaces component in eclipse

Tags: eclipse, primefaces, joinfaces

Content assist and new xhtml page option is not working for joinfaces.
I am following the example project present in [Example](https://github.com/joinfaces/joinfaces-maven-jar-example).
I have tried multiple solution nothing seems to be working.
Not able to create new xhtml page neither getting content assist for bean classes.
Eclipse IDE for java developers 2020-06.

```
 <h:outputText value="#{test.helloWorld.firstName}" />
```

After # nothing is showing but after h it is showing the options.

```
@Component
@ViewScoped
public class Test {
    
    @Getter
    @Setter
    public HelloWorld helloWorld;
    
    @PostConstruct
    public void init() {
        helloWorld = new HelloWorld();
    }
    
    public String changePage() {
        return "success";
    }
    
    public void save() {
        System.out.println("Hello"+helloWorld.getFirstName()+helloWorld.getLastName());
    }

}
```

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.5.0-M2</version>
        <relativePath /> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.ap</groupId>
    <artifactId>test</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>test</name>
    <description>Test</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>8</java.version>
        <joinfaces.version>4.5.0-m2</joinfaces.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.joinfaces</groupId>
                <artifactId>joinfaces-dependencies</artifactId>
                <version>${joinfaces.version}</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.joinfaces</groupId>
            <artifactId>security-spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.joinfaces</groupId>
            <artifactId>primefaces-spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.joinfaces</groupId>
            <artifactId>richfaces-spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <excludes>
                        <exclude>
                            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
                            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
                        </exclude>
                    </excludes>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>spring-milestones</id>
            <name>Spring Milestones</name>
            <url>https://repo.spring.io/milestone</url>
        </repository>
        <repository>
            <id>spring-snapshots</id>
            <name>Spring Snapshots</name>
            <url>https://repo.spring.io/snapshot</url>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>true</enabled>
            </snapshots>
        </repository>
    </repositories>
    <pluginRepositories>
        <pluginRepository>
            <id>spring-milestones</id>
            <name>Spring Milestones</name>
            <url>https://repo.spring.io/milestone</url>
        </pluginRepository>
        <pluginRepository>
            <id>spring-snapshots</id>
            <name>Spring Snapshots</name>
            <url>https://repo.spring.io/snapshot</url>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>true</enabled>
            </snapshots>
        </pluginRepository>
    </pluginRepositories>

</project>
```

Comment: Can you reproduce it with the [_Eclipse IDE for Enterprise(!) Java and Web Developers_](https://www.eclipse.org/downloads/packages/release/2021-03/r/eclipse-ide-enterprise-java-and-web-developers)? Which with editor did you open the file?

Comment: I using normal java editor. I have placed mentioned the example project which I am referring to.

Comment: You said you have an outdated version of the _Eclipse IDE for Java Developers_. But for what you do, you should use the more feature rich _Eclipse IDE for Enterprise(!) Java and Web Developers_, which offers more feature for that than the smaller IDE for Java Developers. Please check whether you missed to upgrade before asking and a [minimal example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) would be nice.

Comment: Yep or even update to Jboss Tools for Eclipse which has much better XHTML JSF support.

Comment: I tried downloading devstudio-10.4.0.GA-installer-eap still it is not working I am using JSF along with spring boot and for bean I am using org.springframework.stereotype.Component instead of managed bean as suggested in https://github.com/joinfaces/joinfaces-maven-jar-example

Comment: In eclipse also I downloaded Jboss Tools JSF from https://download.jboss.org/jbosstools/photon/stable/updates/ but didn't worked can it be because it is not JSF project?