# Content assist not working joinfaces jboss

Tags: spring-boot, primefaces, jboss, joinfaces

I am following this project [Example](https://github.com/joinfaces/joinfaces-maven-jar-example)
I have downloded it and import it as maven project in Jboss Developer Studio but the content assist is not working.
Is there any configuration which need to be done in jboss or it does not support.
The project does not have faces-config.xml or web.xml will adding this help if yes then how to do that.
Please let me know if join faces does not support this.

```
<p:inputText value="ctrl + space not working"/>
```

Comment: I think you have to make sure to add "Web Facet" to your Eclipse project.  I think by default Eclipse sees its a JAR and doesn't add the Web Facet.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Content assist not working for joinfaces component in eclipse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66726665/content-assist-not-working-for-joinfaces-component-in-eclipse)

Comment: That is same question which is asked by me I tried all those solutions but it didn't helped me .